# Get OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition in Toolbar

Tags: geoext, openlayers-2, ext-js

I have created an OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition:

```
var coord = new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({
            prefix: 'You are here: ',
            separator: ' | ',
            numDigits: 5,
            emptyString: 'Mouse is not over map.',
            displayProjection: "EPSG:4326",
            });

        map.addControl(coord);
```

And a Toolbar:

```
  var toolBar = new Ext.Toolbar({
            items: [
                 {
                  xtype: "label",
                  text: "Scale = 1:  ",
                 },
                 {
                    xtype: 'displayfield',
                 }
                ]
            });
```

This Toolbar is the tbar in my mapPanel:

```
var mapPanel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
          region: "center",
          map: map,
          tbar:toolBar
          });
```

Is there any posibillity to get the Value of the Mouse Position as a displayfield in my Toolbar?
I already tried this: http://trac.geoext.org/attachment/ticket/195/195.1.patch,
but my map is not working with "  new GeoExt.Toolbar.ControlDisplay". Is there anything i can use instead?

I am using: OpenLayers 2, GeoExt and ExtJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working for me with a textfield (id: 'TextField') in the tbar and with the code:

```
var test= Ext.getCmp('TextField');
test.setRawValue();
```